# Flutter Laravel Api call csrf token mismatch

Tags: laravel, api, flutter, http-post, csrf

I am trying to authenticate users using API(Laravel API) in flutter. But my post request fails because of CSRF token mismatch. How do I approach this?

```dart
// my API class
postData(data, apiUrl) async { 
    var fullurl = _url + apiUrl;
    print(fullurl);
    print(jsonEncode(data));
    return await http.post(
        fullurl,
        body: jsonEncode(data),
        headers: _setHeaders()
    );
}

_setHeaders() => {
    'Content-type' : 'application/json',
    'Accept' : 'application/json',
};

// in my signup page after submit button is pressed

var data = {
    'name' : _name,
    'email' : _email,
    'password' : _password,
};

var result = await API().postData(data, 'register');
var body = json.decode(result.body);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is your route in `web.php` or `api.php`?

Comment: Take a look at Laravel Sanctum and see if that solves your issue. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#how-it-works

Comment: my routes are in web.php. and I managed to solve them temporarily by putting exceptions in versfycsrftoken.php.

Comment: @Dom ye I was just about to look into sanctum or either passport. I will see how it goes. thank you!